# Objective-C – Have NSSortDescriptor static in Utility class

Tags: objective-c, static

Is it a good idea to have `NSSortDescriptor` declared static in a Utility class? I do some sorting of arrays in my application in perhaps 10 different places. I'm thinking if I can reuse the `NSSortDescriptor` from my Utility class it would use less memory when allocating a new NSSortDescriptor whenever I want to sort something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not?  ObjC classes are lightweight anyhow, and NSSortDescriptor is just an object, and your memory logic is spot on, so long as this isn't just a one time thing.

Answer (score 1):

I say it's a toss up. In normal use, your sort descriptor comes into memory but also (importantly) leaves memory as needed. This may take up cycles, but it is good memory management. Keeping a pointer to it statically may save initialization cycles, but it will keep it in memory when not in use, which is bad memory management.

It is a great idea to centralize your initialization logic, perhaps in a class method of a utility class, but it should not retain the instances it creates for re-use.